# PAC Manager dependencies problem under Centos 7.1

Tags: centos, yum, cpan, pac-manager

I have downloaded [PAC Manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/files/pac-4.0/pac-4.5.5.5-2.x86_64.rpm/download) but when I try to do `yum install` on it, I get dependency errors at the end:

```
Error: Package: pac-4.5.5.5-2.x86_64 (/pac-4.5.5.5-2.x86_64)
       Requires: perl(Gnome2::GConf)
Error: Package: pac-4.5.5.5-2.x86_64 (/pac-4.5.5.5-2.x86_64)
       Requires: perl(Gtk2::GladeXML)
Error: Package: pac-4.5.5.5-2.x86_64 (/pac-4.5.5.5-2.x86_64)
       Requires: perl-Crypt-Blowfish
Error: Package: pac-4.5.5.5-2.x86_64 (/pac-4.5.5.5-2.x86_64)
       Requires: perl(Net::ARP)
Error: Package: pac-4.5.5.5-2.x86_64 (/pac-4.5.5.5-2.x86_64)
       Requires: perl-IO-Stty
```

I have no idea how to satisfy these dependencies, as those are not available in my repositories (list below). I haven't found any working solution over the network.

I tried solution from the last post in [this CentOS forum thread](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=49960), but I am unable to install `Pango` under `cpan` with following error:

```
Pre-requisites not found:
Can't locate Cairo.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at (eval 11) line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 11) line 1.

Please install them manually.
No 'Makefile' created  XAOC/Pango-1.226.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
Failed during this command:
 XAOC/Pango-1.226.tar.gz                      : writemakefile NO -- No 'Makefile' created
```

Which I don't know how to solve.
I also tried to install via `cpan` packages from [Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=906208).
When I omitted `Pango` and tried `Gtk2` it said, that missing dependencies are `Pango` and `Glib`. I had no error during `Glib` installation via `cpan`.

I have following repositories:

```
repo id                     repo name                                     status
adobe-linux-x86_64          Adobe Systems Incorporated                        2
atrpms/7/x86_64             Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - ATrpms    827
base/7/x86_64               CentOS-7 - Base                               8,652
centosplus/7/x86_64         CentOS-7 - Plus                                  43
elrepo                      ELRepo.org Community Enterprise Linux Reposit   150
epel/x86_64                 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_6 8,305
extras/7/x86_64             CentOS-7 - Extras                               149
gf/x86_64                   Ghettoforge packages that won't overwrite cor    91
google-chrome               google-chrome                                     3
nux-dextop/x86_64           Nux.Ro RPMs for general desktop use           1,962
remi                        Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 7 - x86 2,112
remi-debuginfo/x86_64       Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 7 - x86   784
remi-php55                  Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.5 pour Enterprise Li   299
remi-php55-debuginfo/x86_64 Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.5 pour Enterprise Li   199
remi-php56                  Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.6 pour Enterprise Li   302
remi-php56-debuginfo/x86_64 Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.6 pour Enterprise Li   200
remi-safe                   Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Lin   131
remi-test                   Les RPM de remi en test pour Enterprise Linux   384
remi-test-debuginfo/x86_64  Les RPM de remi en test pour Enterprise Linux   116
rpmforge                    RHEL 7 - RPMforge.net - dag                     245
updates/7/x86_64            CentOS-7 - Updates                              967
virtualbox/7/x86_64         Oracle Linux / RHEL / CentOS-7 / x86_64 - Vir     8
```

I think I provided as much details as I could, but I will add any missing information, if I have missed any.

Because of lack of reputation, not all URLs are linked as URLs

**EDIT:**

After I satisfied `Glib` dependency: `Test::ConsistentVersion`, it installed fully and `Gtk2` says only about `Pango` missing.

When I try to install `Pango` via `cpan`, it returns:

```
Running install for module 'Pango'
Running make for X/XA/XAOC/Pango-1.226.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/Pango-1.226-H8GEMA
  No 'Makefile' created
, won't make
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
```

and nothing more, so I have no clue where should I go next.

Answer (score 2):

I have fallen Yesterday in the exact same problem.

I finally ended up locating a nice yum repository that contains all the missing dependencies required by pac-manager : [Nux.Ro RPMs for general desktop use](http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/)

The repo is providing its installer so you should be able to:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
$ sudo yum install -y nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
$ sudo yum install pac
```

Due to a proxy error with yum I ended up wget'ing all the missing packages manually and installing them manually until the dependencies were satisfied.
With the following list (all located in the repo):

- perl-Gnome2-VFS-1.082-1.el7.nux.x86_64.rpm
- perl-Gtk2-Unique-0.05-10.el7.nux.x86_64.rpm
- perl-Gtk2-Ex-Simple-List-0.50-19.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
- perl-IO-Stty-0.03-10.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
- perl-Crypt-Blowfish-2.12.001-5.el7.nux.x86_64.rpm
- perl-Net-ARP-1.0.9-1.el7.nux.x86_64.rpm
- perl-Gnome2-Canvas-1.002-24.el7.nux.x86_64.perl
- Gnome2-1.045-1.el7.nux.x86_64.rpmrpm

Comment: you should also add the command to install pac manager: "yum install pac"

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

Download the TAR file: `pac-4.5.5.5-all.tar.gz`
Unpac the TAR file:

```
tar -xvzf pac-4.5.5.5-all.tar.gz
```

Note: This will create a folder named `pac`

Execute following commands:

```
sudo yum install perl-YAML.noarch
sudo yum install uuid-perl.x86_64
sudo yum install perl-Crypt-CBC.noarch
sudo yum install gtk2.x86_64
sudo yum install gtk2-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install perl-CPAN.noarch
```

Start CPAN in a new terminal by typing:

```
sudo cpan (important: start CPAN ar root)
```

In CPAN shell type:

```
yes
install Test::More
install ExtUtils::PkgConfig
install ExtUtils::Depends
```

Leave the CPAN shell open and switch to another terminal window

Execute following commands:

```
sudo yum install glib2-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install pango-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install epel-release.noarch
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum makecache
sudo yum install unique-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install GConf2-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libglade2-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install perl-Socket6.x86_64
```

Switch back to CPAN shell and type:

```
install Cairo
install Pango
install Gtk2
install Gtk2::Unique
install Net:ARP
install Crypt::Rijndael
install Crypt::Blowfish
install Gtk2::Ex::Simple::List
```

This one will fail so you need to do some editing.

Switch to a new terminal window

```
sudo su
cd /.cpan/build/Genome2-GConf-1.044-iKcoAq/xs
vi GConfEngine.xs
```

Scroll down to the line starting with: `##gboolean gconf_engine_key_is_writable (...)`

Delete the lines until the line starting with: `guint`

Leave an empty line above the line: `guint`

Save the file and exit

```
cd ..
make clean
perl Makefile.PL
make
```

Here you should [b]ONLY[/b] get 2 Warnings. If there are any other messages, you should get back to the editing step (using `vi`) above and check your edits. Remember to leave the empty line above the line `guint` !

When you are done then get back to CPAN shell and continue with:

```
install Gtk2::Ex::Simple::List
install Gnome2::GConf
install Gtk2::GladeXML
cd pac
./pac
```

From: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=49960

Comment: is it required to execute installing packages by yum separately, in the exact order, or can I simply supply all packages to yum at once? keeping them divided by cpan installations of course.

Comment: I did it, step by step, on freshly installed CentOS7. Had no error during install `Gtk2::Ex::Simple::List`, but running `./pac` produces `Can't locate Socket6.pm in @INC`. did `yum install perl-Socket6.x86_64`. Installation of `Gnome2::Gconf` via cpan failed with `TSCH/Gnome2-GConf-1.044.tar.gz: make_test NO`. Installing with `force` did the trick and pac has started - didn't do anything in it yet. I've edited the answer, adding yum package there and fixing capitalization in one of cpan packages.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some updated instructions for **2018** to install **pac manager** in Centos 7 minimal:

```
#!/bin/sh
yum install -y wget
wget http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm 
yum install -y nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm   
yum install -y pac perl-Digest-SHA perl-XML-Parser perl-Gnome2-Vte
find /opt/pac -name Vte.so* -exec rm {} \;
```

& run from the menu or via a terminal as `pac`